# How to define a constructable type which accepts private/protected constructors

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm attempting to implement a function which accepts a generic class/constructor constrained to implementers of a specific interface as an argument. I was able to accomplish that via a "constructable" type (`InterfaceConstructor` in the sample below).

However, I've encountered a complication. One of the class types I need to use this function for requires a private/protected constructor. (i.e. parameters passed to it's constructor must come from a factory method which has pre-validated them and shouldn't be instantiated with `new` from the end user).

Unfortunately, this causes the constructable type to longer match due to public/protected constructor type issues. Can this issue be solved without changing the constructor visibility?

```js
interface Interface { get FooVal(): any; }
type InterfaceContructor = { new(): Interface }
function bar<T extends InterfaceContructor>( bar: T ) { }

class UserClass implements Interface {
    private readonly foo: string;
    get FooVal() { return this.foo; }
    protected constructor( validated_string: string )
    {
        this.foo = validated_string;
    }
    // Static factory methods are provided to instantiate the class for end users of the type
    // ...
}

bar( UserClass ); // Argument of type 'typeof UserClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InterfaceContructor'. Cannot assign a 'protected' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the constructor is private or protected, then `bar` could not call it anyway, so there isn't much point in having that as part of the type that `bar` requires.

---

So if `bar` is intended to call these "Static factory methods" you mention then those methods are what needs to be part of the type that `bar` accepts.

For instance:

```
interface Interface { get FooVal(): any; }
type InterfaceContructor = { makeInstance(): Interface }

function bar<T extends InterfaceContructor>( bar: T ) {
  const instance = bar.makeInstance()
  console.log(instance.FooVal) // fine
}
```

And you just pass it a class constructor that has a static interface that matches that.

```
class UserClass implements Interface {
  private readonly foo: string;
  get FooVal() { return this.foo; }
  
  protected constructor( validated_string: string ) {
      this.foo = validated_string;
  }
  
  static makeInstance() {
    return new this('Hello')
  }
}

bar( UserClass ); // fine
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJyDeyDmEYyAYgPZkBqcANgBQCUAXMnCAJ4DcyAvgFBh2ABxTpIsRBADCZcFACuCMGSjIAvLmQBbOAGsI6AM5g2SRizGZJvPnxjyQS4LOQAjOFAA8AFWQQAHpAgACaGaBgSSDJyispQAHx0bh4svgy4fMjICLLGyKDGpiga7lAAdDr6RiaOEIyZ2blkNBBlNGT4dAU1SGXkVLTpAPRDyDCgEHz8fAg0cIZhAKqG0FJzC-laQi1aEOBhlpEoOA1CUMAAbnCQyFAQcMGyNOxjFCzG5yD4nA2ExP3UejpPB3MDyKAgZBgAAWwEMZRgFG4-CypygZEgSggwUaIA+sRUSSuNGAwWu2IA+h9QPh3mBPvhkMCGlksjC4QiKOpkMTSeTglT6TSflkUcgGoUwMAENo9AY8T06szWbciODISAIAB3KGwwx0ADkAAkIDR2gaGA1+NNSkllqt1mEGNwRmMJkA)

Comment: I think this is the best answer in general for the problem, but I wanted to share another workaround/hack I had been able to solve the issue with for reference.

Using an [empty abstract class and the `typeof` operator as lined out in this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17572#issuecomment-319994873) I could create a constructable type which accepted hidden constructor types while maintaining the type strictness. However, it has the noted drawbacks as per that discussion.